# Clonar uma lista em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, lista-encadeada

Tenho uma classe que lê um arquivo csv e coloco os dados da tabela em uma lista.

```
public class Gerenciador {


    public LinkedList<Acidentes> listAcidentes;

    public Gerenciador() {
        listAcidentes = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void readFile(String nomeArq) {
        try {
            Path path1 = Paths.get(nomeArq);

            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path1, Charset.forName("utf8"));

            String line = reader.readLine();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.replace(",", ".");
                String[] dados = line.split(";");

                //Variaveis para criação do objeto acidente
                String log1 = dados[1]; //Endereço 1
                String log2 = dados[2]; //Endereço 2

                int hora = Integer.parseInt(dados[30]); // Intervalo de hora cheia

                DiaNoite turno = null;                  //Verificação de dia ou noite
                if (dados[21].equalsIgnoreCase("NOITE")) {
                    turno = DiaNoite.NOITE;

                } else {
                    turno = DiaNoite.DIA;

                }

                String dia = dados[28]; //Dia do acidente
                String mes = dados[29]; //Mes do acidente
                String ano = dados[30]; //Ano do acidente


                Clima clima = null; //Verificação do clima (BOM/NULBADO/CHUVOSO)
                if (dados[23].equalsIgnoreCase("BOM")) {
                    clima = Clima.BOM;
                } else if (dados[23].equalsIgnoreCase("NUBLADO")) {
                    clima = Clima.NUBLADO;
                } else {
                    clima = Clima.CHUVOSO;
                }


                DiaSemana diaSemana = null; //Verificação do dia da semana do acidente
                switch (dados[8]) {
                    case "SEGUNDA-FEIRA":
                        diaSemana = DiaSemana.SEGUNDA;
                        break;
                    case "TERÇA-FEIRA":
                        diaSemana = DiaSemana.TERCA;
                        break;
                    case "QUARTA-FEIRA":
                        diaSemana = DiaSemana.QUARTA;
                        break;
                    case "QUINTA-FEIRA":
                        diaSemana = DiaSemana.QUINTA;
                        break;
                    case "SEXTA-FEIRA":
                        diaSemana = DiaSemana.SEXTA;
                        break;
                    case "SABADO":
                        diaSemana = DiaSemana.SABADO;
                        break;
                    case "DOMINGO":
                        diaSemana = DiaSemana.DOMINGO;
                        break;

                }

                //String tipoAcid = dados[5];
                TipoAcid tipoAcid = null;
                switch (dados[5]) {
                    case "CHOQUE":
                        tipoAcid = TipoAcid.CHOQUE;
                        break;
                    case "ABALROAMENTO":
                        tipoAcid = TipoAcid.ABALROAMENTO;
                        break;
                    case "COLISAO":
                        tipoAcid = TipoAcid.COLISAO;
                        break;
                    case "QUEDA":
                        tipoAcid = TipoAcid.QUEDA;
                        break;
                    case "ATROPELAMENTO":
                        tipoAcid = TipoAcid.ATROPELAMENTO;
                        break;
                    case "EVENTUAL":
                        tipoAcid = TipoAcid.EVENTUAL;
                        break;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(dados[35]); //Latitude
                double lon = Double.parseDouble(dados[36]); //Longitude
                GeoPosition pos = new GeoPosition(lat, lon); //Localização do acidente

                Dia d = new Dia(hora, turno, dia, mes, ano, clima, diaSemana); //Criação do dia, para criar um acidente
                Acidentes a = new Acidentes(log1, log2, d, tipoAcid, pos); //Criação do objeto acidente

                listAcidentes.add(a);

            }
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("Erro de E/S: %s%n", x);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
```

Preciso clonar a lista para uma classe de testes, para eu fazer a manipulação desses dados, porém não sei como fazer isso.
Já testei o método clone e não funcionou (Ou então usei ele errado)

Comment: O `clone()` funciona sim. Onde vc está utilizando ele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Vc quer clonar a lista pra uma classe de testes, mas se vc fizer uma instância da sua classe `Gerenciador` na sua classe de testes vc terá lista sem a necessidade de clona-la.

Acredito que não ficou mt claro como seria esse teste que vc quer fazer, mas de qualquer forma o clone() funciona. Na sua classe Gerenciador, vc poderia fazer o seu método `readFile` retornar a lista. Assim:

```
public LinkedList<Acidentes> readFile(String nomeArq) {

    try {

        // CÓDIGO DO SEU MÉTODO.

    } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("Erro de E/S: %s%n", x);
      }
    return listAcidentes;
}
```

Dessa forma na chamada do método em outra classe vc pode fazer o clone da lista e usar na sua classe de testes:

```
//INSTÂNCIA DAS CLASSES
ClasseTeste classeTeste = new ClasseTeste();
Gerenciador gerenciador = new Gerenciador();

//LISTA ORIGINAL
LinkedList lista = gerenciador.readFile(nomeDoArquivo);

//CLONANDO A LISTA
LinkedList listaClonada = new LinkedList(); 
listaClonada = (LinkedList) lista.clone(); 

//UTILIZANDO A LISTA CLONADA NA CLASSE DE TESTES
classeTeste.testar(listaClonada);
```

Não sei se é realmente isso que vc busca, espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma

```
LinkedList segundaLista = new LinkedList(); 
segundaLista = (LinkedList) listAcidentes.clone();
```